# Display none not working inside of media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, display

I am trying to build a nice nav from the ground up. I have some seperators built into my nav as list items. I want these to dissapear when the screen size is smaller.

This is my HTML:

```
 <head>
      <title>Personal Portfolio Page</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav id="top_nav">
    <ul id="nav_ul">
      <li><a href="#">Who </a></li>
      <li class="nav_seperator">|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li class="nav_seperator">|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav_seperator">|</li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
html {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top_nav {

}

#nav_ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 18.5px 20px 18.5px 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#nav_ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
}

#nav_ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav_seperator {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 590px) {

  #nav_ul a{
    background-color: green;
  }

  .nav_seperator {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

The background color green works fine, but the separators do not disappear, any reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set your `#nav_ul li` to `display: auto` in your CSS, as `#nav_ul li` is a higher level of specificity than the `nav_seperator` it takes priority when rendered.

To combat this you should change `.nav_seperator` to `#nav_ul .nav_seperator` in your CSS and the specifier will take priority over the `#nav_ul li` specifier.

This:

```
.nav_seperator {
    display: none;
 }
```

Becomes this:

```
#nav_ul .nav_seperator {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it would be something like this! Did not even think specificity, lapsed my mind. I will set this as solution when I am able.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers will solve it, but if you can't or don't want to change your CSS for some reason try placing the separators in `<p></p>` tags which should work.

E.g.

```html
<nav id="top_nav">
    <ul id="nav_ul">
      <li><a href="#">Who </a></li>
      <li><p class="nav_seperator">|</p></li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
      <li><p class="nav_seperator">|</p></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><p class="nav_seperator">|</p></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```